# Tomcat logs rotating with 2 or more dates in file names and many 0KB files

Tags: tomcat

The Tomcat instances for one of the servers where I operate have logs that are rotating in a weird pattern, with 2 or more dates in file names and many 0KB files, as seen here (/opt/tomcat/instancename/logs folder for one of the instances): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8co.png

The current catalina.out file, for example, isn't even the one without any dates, as you can see by the timestamps in the Changed column.

Can you guys tell me how can I fix this?

---EDIT---
I went to check the logrotate files and noticed only one of the instances has the logs configured for rotation in the /etc/logrotate.d/ folder; this instance happens to be the only one who has the crazy file names, contrary to what I thought. As asked in the comments, here's the logrotate config file for the instance:

```
/opt/tomcat/apigold/logs/* {  
    daily  
    missingok  
    rotate 4  
    size 10M  
}
```

Comment: Are you using [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)? If yes, please add the relevant `/etc/logrotate.conf` or `/etc/logrotate.d/` configuration files to your question.

Comment: OK. I added the /etc/logrotate.d/ configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [logrotate man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) :

> Please use wildcards with caution. If you specify *, logrotate will rotate all files, including previously rotated ones. A way around this is to use the olddir directive or a more exact wildcard (such as *.log).

So your config file should be :

```
/opt/tomcat/apigold/logs/*.log {  
    daily  
    missingok  
    rotate 4  
    size 10M  
}
```